# github project need to be uploaded and let other users to contribute

Tags: git, github

I am new to github. I have a project that I need it to be on Github.

How I can upload my project to github.

i heard there is a console based app, using which user can upload project and create repository. How I can download it and use it(it there a tutorial on that?)?

I also need to know how I can let other use contribute to my project?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably referring to [Git](https://git-scm.com/). Git is a version control system which one of its features is distributed remote repositories such as GitHub.

You should start by [setting up git](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/) and reading about using Git.

Comment: thanks, i ll be reading it

Comment: can u tell the difference between git and github?

Comment: Github is what so called a remote repository. In its most basic form it stores your code (and other version-controlled files).
Git on the other hand is a whole system designed to help you to version control your files. Git is independent of Github. Again, that's the most shallow explanation.

Comment: so basically both git and github offers remote repository. am i right?

Comment: No, you can say that Github is only a component of git and again, it is not mandatory for using it.

Comment: what i am getting is 1) one can upload project to git 2) and make that project available to github where other users can view my project and download it. The question i dont understand is how can i allow other programmers to improve my project (because it will be open-source)? does that include the use of git or github?

Comment: You cannot "upload" your project to git, as you cannot upload your project to SVN or Perforce. Git is a system not a website. You can upload (or better say push) your project to Github for your other team members to collaborate on. Again, I suggest to at least walk through some basic tutorial to first understand the terminology.

Comment: Git is a version control system. GitHub is a repository hosting site that uses git.